# Guardar formulario de reportes

Tags: php, html, mysql

Este formulario me ha estado sacando canas desde hace unas horas y de plano ya no encuentro cual es la causa por la que no se guarde.

Tengo el siguiente código PHP, el cual uso para guardar un formulario en la BD

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 $conexion = mysqli("localhost","root","","cbtahd");
 if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
 if(!isset($_POST["guardarReporte"])){
 $emisor = $_POST["emisor"];
 $sucursal = $_POST["sucursal"];
 $area = $_POST["area"];
 $ip = $_POST["ip"];
 $extension = $_POST["extension"];
 $receptor = $_POST["receptor"];
 $reporte = $_POST["reporte"];
 $fechaemi = $_POST["fechaemi"];    
 $email = $_SESSION["user"];
 $insertar = "INSERT INTO tblreportes (emisor,sucursal,area,ip,extension,receptor,reporte,fechaEmi,email) VALUES ('$emisor', '$sucursal','$area','$ip','$extension','$receptor','$reporte','$fechaemi','$email')";
mysqli_query($insertar);
}
}
?>
```

La parte del html es la siguiente

```
<form method="post" action="registrar.php">
        <h1><p class="text-center">Crear reporte</p></h1>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="emisor">Emisor</label>
          <input type="text" name="emisor" id="emisor" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sucursal">Sucursal</label>
          <input type="text" name="sucursal" id="sucursal" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="area">Area</label>
          <input type="text" name="area" id="area" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="ip">IP</label>
          <input type="text" name="ip" id="ip" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="extension">Extension</label>
          <input type="text" name="extension" id="extension" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="receptor">Receptor</label>
          <input type="text" name="receptor" id="receptor" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="reporte">Reporte</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="reporte" name="reporte" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
        </div>

          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fechaEmi">Fecha de emision</label>
          <input type="text" name="fechaemi" id="fechaemi" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <a href="logout.php">ffgfgfgdg</a>
          <input type="button" name="guardarReporte" id="guardarReporte" value="Enviar Reporte" class="btn btn-info">
        </div>
        <span id="result"></span>
      </form>
```

Cuando pongo la sentencia en el Workbench me registra los datos correctamente.
[image: Query en el workbench actualizado]

Comment: ¿Has probado  a leer el resultado del insert para ver si hay algún error?¿Podrías compartir los valores del formulario y el formato de la tabla en la base de datos?

Comment: Aparte de eso, debes usar sentencias preparadas en lugar de sentencias dinámicas que hacen que el código sea  vulnerable a  inyección SQL

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Ya corri el query en el Workbench y me inserta los datos correctamente, pero desde el codigo PHP no los inserta. Lo de sentencias preparadas no me quedo muy claro... Te refieres a PA?

Comment: No es el mismo `insert` en tu código y en la imagen tomada del workbench (tienen diferente número de campos). Lo de las sentencias preparadas es porque tal y como está ahora el código, no se sanean las entradas y podrías tener problemas de seguridad (inyección SQL). Puedes leer más sobre el tema de seguridad en la [página oficial de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Acabo de volver a actualizar el codigo en php y probe nuevamente el query en el workbench y sigue sin dar respuesta. Edite el post de nuevo para que puedas apreciarlo. Y sobre las sentencias preparadas, pues lo tomare en cuenta cuando haga la actualizacion de este proyecto. Apenas voy empezando a programar del lado servidor.

Comment: Parece que hay un error con los `if` que van negados y eso hará que no se entre en ellos (al menos en el caso de "guardarReporte")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay al menos un problema con los condicionales del código que hará que nunca se ejecute la sentencia de inserción:

```
if(!isset($_POST["guardarReporte"])){
```

En tu formulario, el botón para enviar los datos es éste:

```
<input type="button" name="guardarReporte" id="guardarReporte" value="Enviar Reporte" class="btn btn-info">
```

Por lo tanto, siempre que se envíe el formulario, `guardarReporte` estará en la lista de parámetros pasados y el condicional no se cumplirá y no se insertará nada. Debería ir sin la negación:

```
if(isset($_POST["guardarReporte"])){
```

Y puede que tengas que hacer lo mismo con el primer `if` porque no sé si tiene mucho sentido que se inserte si el usuario no está logeado.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda! No había notado que tenia una negación dentro de mi código.